# Grafana prometheus variables don't work when including regex

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I'm trying to filter out panel using variables(job), it works but to clean the resulten drop down menu I have included regex to narrow down the output menu and once I do that the panels don't work anymore. It must be something in using the variables in the panel query but I'm not able to figure it out :
This is my panel query working perfectly with the following variable
[image]
[image]

and once I add the following regex :
[image]

my values disappear although the job name on the panel is the one that contains the regex

[image]

Comment: Why the job picklist shows "spark_latentapp" and the regex is only capable to select "spark_latent" (without the "app" at the end)?